# How to call Get-AzSubscription inside Azure function

Tags: azure, function

I created azure function with Powershell option 7.2
under app file -> requirements.pds1, decommented '8.*
and introduced

Import-Module MsOnline -UseWindowsPowershell
Import-Module Partnerenter -UseWindowsPowershell

in  my run.ps1

Despite these changes , I am getting below error

the Term Get-AzSubscription

Please help to fix this issue

Thanks in advance
Ramabadran

Comment: `Get-AzSubscription` is part of module [Az.Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azsubscription?view=azps-8.3.0). So you have to import it: `Import-Module Az.Accounts`

Answer (score 0):

Please be informed that if you're using Azure functions then its installed already.

You might be having some syntax issue that you may need to check or you might have referenced AzureRM comand let before Az commandlet.
Please review your code first. The better option would be to enabled verbose logging using -verbose switch.

You can even import module using command Import-Module but in my opinion this is not required knowing this module is preinstalled on PAAS offering by default.

Comment: Thanks Rohit , I am new to Azure Power shell and Azure functions

I am executing the powershell command inside the Azure function. 

I am getting "Get-AzResource/Get-AzSubscription/Get-AzModule" is not recognized as a name of cmdlet or function or Scrip file or executable program
but while executing the "Get-Date" I am getting required results

It is great , if you can suggest how to fixes to this issue
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. In VS Code > Create an Azure Function Project in the local workspace with the PowerShell Runtime Stack (7.2 Version)
2. Run these cmdlets `Install-Module Az`, `Import-Module Az` in the project workspace/path of the terminal.
3. In `requirements.psd1`, uncomment the line `'Az' = '8.*'`.